how to catch csrf error in controller in ci4?
I want to do something when csrf validation failed in controller,
I am having a hard time figuring this out,
Check out the code below,
View => csrf.php,
<?= session()->getFlashdata('error') ?>
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url('/test_csrf')?>">
    <?= csrf_field() ?>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Controller => Welcome.php,
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Security\Exceptions\SecurityException;

class Welcome extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // $this->middleware('MyFilter');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello, this is your first controller in CodeIgniter 4!';
    }

    public function csrf(){
        return view('csrf');
    }

    public function test_csrf(){
        // do something when csrf failed here.
    }
}


The easiest way would be to make a copy of the CI CSRF-Filter, implement your own logic there and use it in your Filters.php file.
CI's CSRF.php (see comments):
public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        if (! $request instanceof IncomingRequest) {
            return;
        }

        $security = service('security');

        try {
            $security->verify($request);
        } catch (SecurityException $e) {
            if ($security->shouldRedirect() && ! $request->isAJAX()) {
                // Instead of the following line, you could implement your own redirect here
                // You probably need to take a look at shouldRedirect() too resp. replace it
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
            }

            throw $e;
        }
    }

